# Evaluate $\operatorname{lim}_{n\to\infty} \int_0^\infty \frac{n^2x}{1+x^2} e^{-n^2x^2} dx$

Tags: real-analysis

Evaluate the following limit for $a=0$ and for $a>0$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_a^\infty \frac{n^2x}{1+x^2} e^{-n^2x^2} dx.$$

For $a>0$, I can use dominated convergence theorem as $\frac{n^2x}{1+x^2} e^{-n^2x^2}\leq \frac{1}{x(1+x^2)}\in L^1(a,\infty)$, then the limit can be put into the integral to get the limit as $0$. But I'm not sure how to approach the case $a=0$. Can you please give me some hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a change of variable, call $nx=t$. Then your limit becomes
$$\lim_{n \to + \infty} \int_0^{+ \infty} \frac{t}{1+(t/n)^2} e^{-t^2} \mathrm dt$$
Since
$$0 \le \frac{t}{1+(t/n)^2} e^{-t^2} \le te^{-t^2}$$
You can apply dominated convergence theorem, so that the limit is equal to
$$\int_0^{+ \infty} t e^{-t^2}\mathrm dt = \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

*Just for your curiosity.*
$$\frac{n^2x}{1+x^2} e^{-n^2x^2}=e^{n^2}n^2 x\frac{e^{-n^2(1+x^2)}} {1+x^2 }$$
$$I=\int\frac{n^2x}{1+x^2} e^{-n^2x^2}\,dx=\frac 12e^{n^2}n^2\int \frac{e^{-n^2(1+x^2)}} {1+x^2 }\,d(1+x^2)$$ I suppose that the change of variable $t=1+x^2$ is clear and it makes
$$I=\frac{1}{2} e^{n^2} n^2 \,\text{Ei}\left(-n^2 \left(1+x^2\right)\right)$$ where appears the exponential integral function.
$$J=\int_0^\infty\frac{n^2x}{1+x^2} e^{-n^2x^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{2} e^{n^2} n^2\, \Gamma \left(0,n^2\right)$$ the expansion of which being
$$J=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$